# как открыть много окон, вместо вкладок

Tags: python, webbrowser

пишу код, в нем нужно открыть много окон браузера и в каждом окне ссылку

вот код:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open.new(' https://vk.com ')
```

но при исполнения кода открывается просто новая вкладка в открытом окне, а мне нужно что-бы открывалось именно новое окно с этой ссылкой

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html):

> Display url using the default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible. If new is 1, a new browser window is opened if possible.

> Открывает url используя браузер по умолчанию. Если `new` - 0, url открывается в том же окне браузера, если это возмжно. Если `new` - 1, то открывается новое окно браузера, если это возможно.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://vk.com', new=1)
```

Или можно использовать функцию `open_new`:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new('https://vk.com')
```